# Expansion of an ideal gas at constant pressure

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, work, ideal-gas, gas

I approach these expansion problems like so: 
The gas and the surroundings(piston+outside) are at the same pressure at first. We heat the gas. The pressure rises inside the syringe *a bit*. The gas expands so the pressure remains constant. Then I use P(the constant pressure of the gas) *dV. What I want to confirm is my reasoning on using this equation. It was derived assuming P(internal) = constant. But it does change momentarily. Is the reason we ignore it in the "a bit" nature?

Also for compression, the force exerted on the gas by surroundings (piston+outside)  is taken as the force the gas exerts on the piston. Is this Newton's third law?

Comment: What do you mean by _"Is the reason we ignore it in the "a bit" nature?"_

Comment: As in the as soon as pressure rises because of the temp rise the volume expands to "counter it".  So pressure never really changes much. So it's okay to ignore it for calculations

Comment: @KV18^^^^^>>>>>

Comment: @KV18, I forgot to tag you. So I put this up sign to refer you up.

Comment: Nah. It is alright. It does display in my feed anyway.

Comment: Newton's 3rd law says that the force exerted by the inside face of the piston on the gas is equal to the force that the gas exerts on the inside face of the piston.  This is true even for rapid irreversible expansions and compressions of the gas.

Answer (score 1):

> As in the as soon as pressure rises because of the temp rise the volume expands to "counter it". So pressure never really changes much. So it's okay to ignore it for calculations

If the piston moves by a little bit, then the pressure is literally the same. Considering $\Delta V \to 0$ which would mean $\Delta V \approx dV$.

> Also for compression, the force exerted on the gas by surroundings (piston+outside) is taken as the force the gas exerts on the piston. Is this Newton's third law?

Yes, this is true.

Comment: the problem I was doing had the piston moving somewhat more than what I guess would be appropriate to call a little. Can't the relatively constant pressure argument be used for that?

Comment: That is why we integrate. We neglect infinitesimal changes in the pressure although we consider the change for the volume to be $dV$, and we integrate along the volume to find the work done. It is more of a mathematical trick. Sure, when we integrate, it becomes clear that the change in the pressure of the gas is a lot.

Comment: apologies for the late reply. In such situations, my teacher told me to use W=PdV since P is more or less constant. Is this also since P doesn't change much ?

Comment: Yes, for that infinitesimal change $dV$, the pressure does not change much.

Comment: we did questions where we just multiplied P ( taken constant) and the whole change in volume. The argument here is that since pressure never changed much through the process, we get to use this? No integration or differentiation was used.

Comment: As you said, $P$ was taken to be constant throughout the process. So $P$ in such cases are not a function of $V$.

Comment: Yes but my concern was even though we assume P to be constant, it _must_ have change a little ( otherwise there would be no expansion). So my query is when my question says "the gas is expanded at constant pressure" the constant means almost constant and not 100% constant, yea?

Answer (score 1):

If the heat addition occurs very slowly such that the pressure and temperature gradients in the gas approach zero, the process can be considered quasi-static and the pressure of the gas will always be very close to the external pressure. If the process is also frictionless, then we can say it is a reversible isobaric expansion. At every point along the process the ideal gas equation applies

$$\frac{V}{T}=\frac{nR}{P}$$

since $P$ is constant

$$\frac{V}{T}=constant$$

Since the external force applied to the gas by the piston and atmosphere is always approximately equal to and opposite the force the piston and atmosphere apply to the gas, Newton;s third law applies.

Hope this helps.